# how to report/query the recipients of email alerts

Tags: administration, workflow, email-alert

When I am deactivating a user I get a warning to say that they are included in email alerts and so cannot be deactivated. However, as I have hundreds of email alerts set-up, it is not practical to go through each one manually to find the offending alert/s. Additionally it is not possible to display the recipient of the alert in the email alerts list view. Therefore i need to be able to query or report on the email alert object to find this information. How can I report on email alerts and show the recipient value for the alert.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I don't believe I ever found a solution for that one, sorry!

Comment: You can use Force.com IDE to find out specific email alerts.

1. Create a new force.com project
2. Add all the email alerts to the project and save.
3. Open the Object.workflow source component (it will be in XML format).
4. Use normal Ctrl + F, find option, to search user names and then, check the associated email alerts.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by searching your workflows metadata.
For example in an Eclipse project you could use the file search functionality to search for the user email in all the *.workflow files in your current project.

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE** this answer is incorrect. Check melmoussaoui's answers for the correct way of handling this.

You can use Tooling API for this and query the WorkFlowAlert table from developer console:

1. Open Developer Console >
2. Click on Query Editor
3. Check "Use Tooling API"
4. Set query, e.g. SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Description, CcEmails, SenderType, TemplateId FROM WorkFlowAlert WHERE CcEmails like '%the.user@email.com%'
5. Click Execute

Comment: How would one get the NON ccemail recipients? thanks

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My answer is (unfortunately) incorrect because non cc-email recipients cannot be queried from the Tooling API. The only decent solution is to use the metadata API to query all workflows (in Eclipse or VSCode) and do a search for the user's email address.